# Add dependency on Shell32.lib to WDK makefile

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, wdk

I've successfully powered my way through the WDK XPSDrv sample project and modified it to do what I need. However, I absolutely cannot figure out how to get the build scripts to reference/include/whatever shell32.lib. I'm a .NET guy! This is strange and terrifying territory.

I think adding a dependency reference is what I need to do. When I compile I get this error

```
3>errors in directory c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\src\printgit\xpsdrvsmpl\
src\filters\common
3>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\src\printgit\xpsdrvsmpl\src\filters\common\
xdstrmflt.cpp(238) : error C3861: 'ShellExecute': identifier not found
```

Due to my extreme lack of knowledge (and hurry) I'm not using visual studio, just simple mods in notepad++ and the shell wdk build environment. I have a surrogate project in VS where I've been writing and testing small chunks of code. In that project I added a Dependency library to `shell32.lib` and everything worked perfectly.

There's a makefile that references a `sources`, the contents are below.

Not that it matters, but the code that requires shell32 is

```
HINSTANCE statu = ShellExecute(NULL,TEXT("open"),szTempFileName,NULL,NULL,9);
```

Here's the `sources` file.

```
INCLUDES=$(INCLUDES);        \
    .\;                      \
    .\..\inc;                \
    .\..\debug;              \
    $(DDK_INC_PATH);         \
    $(SDK_INC_PATH)\gdiplus; \

USE_ATL=1
USE_STL=1

ATL_VER=70
STL_VER=70

# We use STL 7.0, which is not available pre-Vista. We therefore set USE_LIBCMT=1
# If STL 7.0 is not necessary, USE_MSVCRT=1 is recommended
USE_LIBCMT=1

USE_IDLBASED_DLLDATA=1
USE_OBJECT_ROOT=1

MSC_WARNING_LEVEL=/W4 /WX

USE_NATIVE_EH=1

PRECOMPILED_CXX=1
PRECOMPILED_INCLUDE=precomp.h

# To remove debug code remove -DDBG from the line below
C_DEFINES=$(C_DEFINES) -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE

SOURCES=\
    bkpchndlr.cpp       \
    bkpthndlr.cpp       \
    bkschema.cpp        \
    cmpthndlr.cpp       \
    cmprofpthndlr.cpp   \
    cmprofpchndlr.cpp   \
    cmintpthndlr.cpp    \
    cmschema.cpp        \
    cmprofileschema.cpp \
    cmintentsschema.cpp \
    globals.cpp         \
    nupschema.cpp       \
    nupchndlr.cpp       \
    nupthndlr.cpp       \
    pchndlr.cpp         \
    pgscpchndlr.cpp     \
    pgscpthndlr.cpp     \
    pgscschema.cpp      \
    porientpthndlr.cpp  \
    porientschema.cpp   \
    psizepthndlr.cpp    \
    psizeschema.cpp     \
    pimagepthndlr.cpp   \
    pimageschema.cpp    \
    pshndlr.cpp         \
    pthndlr.cpp         \
    ptquerybld.cpp      \
    schema.cpp          \
    wmpchndlr.cpp       \
    wmpthndlr.cpp       \
    wmschema.cpp        \
    workbuff.cpp

TARGETNAME=xdsmplcmn
TARGETTYPE=LIBRARY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in your `sources` file:

```
TARGETLIBS=$(SDK_LIB_PATH)\kernel32.lib $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\user32.lib $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\shell32.lib
```

... amend as needed ;)

However, your error is actually *not* a linker error but a compiler error, so you'll likely want to include the header that declares `ShellExecute`, which is `shellapi.h`, in some way.

---

Just looked the sample up in my WDK (7600.16385.1) and as a matter of fact you removed the very important part reproduced below, to which you just would have to append the other `.lib` files to link against:

```
TARGETLIBS=                                  \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\kernel32.lib             \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\user32.lib               \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\winspool.lib             \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\ole32.lib                \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\oleaut32.lib             \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\advapi32.lib             \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\msxml6.lib               \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\uuid.lib                 \
    $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\Comdlg32.lib             \
    $(OBJ_PATH)\..\debug\$O\xdsdbg.lib \
    $(OBJ_PATH)\..\common\$O\xdsmplcmn.lib \
```

... apologies, there are plenty of `sources` files as part of this sample, so of course I cannot really know which of the samples you modified and are trying to build :)

Comment: You are a saint. I had just figured out the sources thing by astrogrepping EVERYTHING for kernel32.lib to find an example. Probably would've pulled my hair out before I realized it was a compiler error though.

Comment: The headers included on my visual studio test app must have included shellapi.h somewhere because it wasn't an include on my test project, which worked fine. weird.

Comment: @scaryman: possibly through the precompiled header `stdafx.h` which includes all kinds of stuff when including `Windows.h` and where one often finds `#define`s before that `#include` in order to prevent certain implicit `#include`s from happening through `Windows.h` and so on. Of course certain MFC/ATL/WTL headers that you may have been using could also make use of `shellapi.h`.